# Fixing the code in python / Bioinformatics

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, bioinformatics

I´m trying to fix this code below.

```
  from pylab import *
    protein = ''
    amino_acids = ['P', 'G', 'L', 'A']
    while ________:
        protein += choice(amino_acids)

    if len(protein) == 1000:
        print(protein)
```

The result I want to get is a random protein of length 1000 comprising of the four given amino acids (P,G,L and A). What is wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? It doesn't work with `________` as your `while` loop conditional.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution (amongst others, maybe more pythonic) would be

```
from pylab import *
protein = ''
amino_acids = ['P', 'G', 'L', 'A']
while len(protein) <= 1000:
    protein = protein + choice(amino_acids)

print(protein)
```

Here, you create an empty string `protein`. The `while` loops starts and appends a random element from `amino_acids` until a string length of 1000 is reached.

A one-liner would be

```
proteins = ''.join([choice(amino_acids) for x in range(1000)])
```

Here, a so-called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is used to generate 1000 choices from `amino_acids`. The 1000 elements are stored as a list. Applying `join` colapses the elements to a single string.

Note that the `''` means that we don't want a separator between our amino acids. Using e.g. `'-'` instead would result in something like

```
L-A-P-G-L-...
```

Comment: Thanks for helping :) How can I run this code by using for-loop instead of while-loop?

Comment: @berr Your're welcome. It is easy to apply a `for` loop when understanding what the difference is to `while` and what they have in common. You can use `for` to count a variable and finish when the variable reached 1000.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do this is to generate a list of random numbers and then use a for loop to loop through the  random number list and append onto the protein string.

```
import random
rand_num=[]
protein=''
amino=['P', 'G', 'L', 'A']

for i in range(1000):
    x=ranom.randint(0,(len(amino)-1))
    rand_num.append(x)

for index in rand_num:
    protein+=amino[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
import random

amino_acids = ['P', 'G', 'L', 'A']
N = 10  # should be 1000 in your case
protein = ''.join( aa for aa in random.choices(amino_acids, k=N) )
```

As defined above, protein could be 'PLLGAPAPGA'.